# how to make two reports(.rdlc) using single DataSet.xsd

Tags: c#, report

I am developing a stand alone windows forms application in C#.
I have to include 5 reports.[Going to use Microsoft Report Viewer]
I think single report viewer on a form will do that.
I will have to take 5 report files ( .rdlc ).
Now I need to create Dataset.xsd file right?
But do I need 5 Dataset.xsd files or single Dataset.xsd will do that?
For every report select query changes, so what to do?
Also I want to do every thing at run time(as far as possible).

I want to create only one Dataset.xsd file & want to change query at run time,
then assign report file(.rdlc) to report viewer.

I am very confused, how these things work!!
also what is the difference between DataSet & Dataset.xsd.

Can I make reports without using any DataSet.xsd file ?

Answer (score 1):

XSD for datasets is usually used to specify types of a dataset's data (like this):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXmlSchema(@"...\Sample.xsd");
ds.ReadXml(@"...\Sample.xml");

ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
rds.Name = "Sample";
rds.Value = ds.Tables[0];
```

You can use any `DataTable`, `IEnumerable`, `BindingSource` or `System.Web.UI.IDataSource` as the value of a `ReportDataSource`. So **yes**, you can make reports without using a DataSet.xsd file.

Then you simply add the `ReportDataSource` to your `ReportViewer`:

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
```

That said, to generate multiple reports using many report definitions, you can use only one data source (if your data are the same).

Comment: Thanks for reply, going to try.

Comment: How can I specify database path at run time for reports, because it will change on user's computer. I don't want to store it in connection string in config or any file.

Comment: Sumit@: considering your setup, you do NOT care about the database! You only care about this line `rds.Value = data;` from my answer. You can read the `data` from anywhere (xml, arrays, Lists, data sources, ...). If you do not know how to connect to a database at runtime (at all), ask a new question on SO, because that question really does not have much in common with this question.